# Need a javascript color wheel with some added functionality

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, prestashop, color-wheel

I need a javascript color picker/ wheel from where user can select a color. Since it is a paint shop, after selecting the color it should send the color value to cart. I'm using prestashop for the shop. Please suggest a wheel/picker which can be easily implemented. I'm open to code the cart part, but I don't want to add the user selection function too)limited skill, :P!). Thanks a lot for the help!.

Answer (score 2):

I use: http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic

for all my colour wheel needs

Answer (score 1):

How about this: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Edit: You can use the `onChange` event to do your processing once the user has selected a color.